# 'unexpectedly found nil' for search in UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisearchbar

I recently tried changing my `UITableViewController` to a `UITableView` within a `UIView`. I changed back to this as I was experiencing an error with my `UISearchBar`, as when I would tap a key to search my app would crash with the error:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

on this line:

```
var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("rideCell")  as! RideCell
```

When I switched back to the `UITableViewController` this error went away and everything was fine, however I've just tested it again and it is again giving me that error.

Anyone have any suggestions? It works fine for the normal table view, it's just when I go to do a search that it crashes. The identifier is definitely correct.

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

Full function:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("rideCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! RideCell

    var ride: Ride

    if tableView == self.searchDisplayController?.searchResultsTableView {
        ride = DataManager.sharedInstance.getRideByName(searchResults[indexPath.row].name)!
    } else {
        ride = DataManager.sharedInstance.rideAtLocation(indexPath.row)!
    }

    cell.rideNameLabel.text = ride.name

    var dateSinceUpdate = NSDate().timeIntervalSinceDate(ride.updated!)
    var secondsSinceUpdate = Int(dateSinceUpdate)
    var timeSinceUpdate = printSecondsConvert(secondsSinceUpdate)

    cell.updatedLabel.text = timeSinceUpdate

    if ride.waitTime == "Closed" {
        cell.waitTimeLabel.text = ride.waitTime!
        cell.timeBackgroundView.backgroundColor = getColorFromNumber(80)
        cell.waitTimeLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir", size: 13)
    } else {
        cell.waitTimeLabel.text = "\(ride.waitTime!)m"
        cell.timeBackgroundView.backgroundColor = getColorFromNumber(ride.waitTime!.toInt()!)
        cell.waitTimeLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir", size: 17)
    }

    AsyncImageLoader.sharedLoader().cancelLoadingURL(cell.rideImageView.imageURL)
    cell.rideImageView.image = UIImage(named: "Unloaded")
    cell.rideImageView.imageURL = NSURL(string: ride.rideImageSmall!)

    return cell
}
```

Comment: You need to register the cell re-use identifier `rideCell` against the class `RideCell` - if you are using a storyboard, you do this via the prototype cell

Comment: Yeah, I've done that. The custom class is set, and the identifier is set.

Comment: Then double check everything, because the exception says that `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` is returning nil - this means that the cell reuse identifier isn't registered to a class. Make sure your table view in your scene is linked to the IBOutlet in your view controller.

Comment: But like I say, it works perfectly for the normal tableView. It's just the searchViewController that doesn't work.

Comment: I can't tell you any more with what you have shown - If that line is returning nil then it is because the `tableview` in that function call doesn't have a class registered for that reuse identifier.

Comment: Not sure what else I can provide... I'll update my question with the entire function, but I don't think the rest is really relevant.

Comment: You probably just need to do some more debugging - check that the value of `tableView` is the same as your IBOutlet - it could be a different table view

Comment: The `if tableview == ...` line leads me to believe that you have more than one tableview, so possibly you are de queuing the cell on the wrong tableview or you need to register the reuse identifier on the other tableview as well

Comment: I've changed the name of the tableView to `ridesTableView`, which has stopped the app from crashing, but is not displaying any results. The only `UITableView` I have is the `ridesTableView` and the search controller.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84855/discussion-between-paulw11-and-user3746428).

Comment: @user3746428 Can you share your project on anywhere? Are you using `UISearchController` or `UISearchDisplayController`?

Comment: I'd rather not if possible. I'm using a `UISearchDisplayController`.

Comment: @user3746428 Do you have registered the cell on `searchResultsTableView`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Discovered an extremely simple solution to the issue. Had to change this:

```
var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("rideCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! RideCell
```

to this:

```
var cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("rideCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! RideCell
```

Comment: Nice answer. Literally have no idea why this should be the case, but it works!

Comment: i will bang my head against the wall for this. No idea why this worked. Aren't they exactly the same

Comment: It's because it's trying to use `tableView` passed as a parameter, which is the search box's own table view. `self.tableView` forced it to use the main table view.

Answer (score 7):

There are a few possibilities that you are seeing a **`fatal error`** of `nil` message in your dialog.

**Possibility #1:** Make sure you have a subclass of `UITableViewCell` named `RideTableViewCell.swift`.
To create a subclass of UITableViewCell simply follow the procedures below.

1. Right-Click on your Project name and create **New File...** in
   **Project Navigator**
2. From **iOS->Source** create **Cocoa Touch Class**
3. In Option Dialog Subclass Field Type **UITableViewCell**
   [image]
4. I believe you have an Custom XIB file already, if not, Check **Also create XIB file**
5. Make sure you input your XIB **identifier** in **Attribute Inspector**

[image]

6. Register your cell class in `viewDidLoad()` function like so:

   `let nibCell = UINib(nibName: "RideTableViewCell", bundle: nil)
    self.tableView.registerNib(nibPosts, forCellReuseIdentifier: "RideCell")`
7. Register your custom cell in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` like so:

   `let cell: RideTableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("RideCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! RideTableViewCell`

---

**Possibility #2:** Maybe when you create your custom XIB you didn't tell it which class it belongs to. To set the class of XIB, follow the procedures below.

1. Click on your **.xib** file in **Project Navigator**
2. Go to **identity inspector** of your cell and make sure `RideTableViewCell` is in there.

[image]

Please comment if you have any question. Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

Please check did you have given proper class name (RideCell), filled proper module(Your target) and finally the identifier in the storyboard. If this is ok please share SS of your storyboard tableView cell.

[image]

and
[image]

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using UITableViewController, then check the following extension are added or not.

```
class XYZViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate,UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchDisplayDelegate, UISearchResultsUpdating
{
```

or Check this [Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/76519/add-table-view-search-swift). It might help you to solve this error.

Answer (score 1):

Please check that your delegates have been properly set in viewDidLoad and that you are inheriting delegate methods of UITableView and search functions like so:

```
class YourClass: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    func viewDidLoad() {
       tableView.delegate = self
       tableView.dataSource = self
    }

}
```

and do the same for the search bar delegates and data sources. More on that [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchDisplayController_Class/).

Answer (score 1):

It is showing nil because there is no UItableViewCell which is of type RideCell. You  have to create a new RideCell.swift which will be a subclass of UITableViewCell and then associate that with the cell of your tableView and then proceed .

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you fill the correct parameters in the code below.

```
private let cellReuseIdentifier = "MyCell"

tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "MyCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier)
```